# Regex a specific version

Tags: regex

I tried a lot of ways to handle my problem with regex, but it doesn't work

Here is an example of the string I try to catch:

"Version 3.2.1"

So There are many ways that the version can be, such as :

"Version 3.2.1"
"Version 3.5"
"Version 3"
"Version 3.8.1"
"Version 3.0"

So I want to match the string if the version is between 1.0.0 and 3.5.1
And it can match for example:

"Version 3.0"
"Version 3"
"Version 2.9.9"
...

And of course, don't match if the string is :
"Version 3.5.1"
"Version 0.9.9"
"Version 4"

Anyone experimented can help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try with this one `^Version ([12](?:\.\d+)*|3(?:\.[0-4](?:\.\d+)*|\.5(?:\.0)*)?)$`.

Comment: Thanks, for help, but it doesn't work at all, I try to modify your regex

Comment: Sorry. Missed a few characters. Just tweaked.